# Parameters from redirect follow '#', how to get using vue router?

Tags: vue.js, oauth-2.0, vue-router, zoho

I am using Zoho API to get an OAUTH2 token.

After authenticating, it redirects back to my url, but the format is as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/#&access_token=ABC123&expires_in=3600&location=us&api_domain=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zohoapis.com
```

Normally URL params are in the format ?access_token=ABC123&expires_in=3600...

Which can be accessed via $this.route.query

However, I'm not sure why the hashtag symbol is being applied here instead of the query params.

Is there an easy way to extract these params using vue router, or do I need to resort to string manipulation / manual parsing?

Comment: Is there any options in zoho to change the redirect URI? The issue is the `#&` VS `#?` right?

Comment: The hashtag (#) usually appears in an anchor tag when you don't want the link to go off the page on which it appears. Are you trying to access the Zoho API URL via an anchor tag on your page?